# Angular2: Convert dynamic component loading from rc.4 to rc5

Tags: angular

now that ComponentResolver has been deprecated , can anyone help convert this code to rc.5?

```
   const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplate/master/src/comps/app2/notes/LoadMeComp.ts';
        const importer = url => Observable.fromPromise(System.import(url));
        const resolve = comp => Observable.fromPromise(this.compResolver.resolveComponent(comp));
        importer(url)
            .switchMap(comp => resolve(comp['LoadMeComp']))
            .subscribe(factory
       => this.putStuffHere.createComponent(factory))
```

this is how far I got... no luck still

```
        const url =      
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplate/master/src/comps/app2/notes/LoadMeComp.ts';

        const importer = url => Observable.fromPromise(System.import(url));
        //let type: Type = ...;
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(type);
        factory.create(injector);
        let componentRef = <ComponentRef<any>>factory.create(injector);
        return new Promise<ComponentRef<any>>((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(componentRef) ;
        });
```

plunkr in progress: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lxsc5XgdBiiGAy47dUxc?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

use [Compiler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Compiler-class.html) class

instead of `this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(type)`
use `this.compiler.compileComponentAsync(type).then((cmpFactory))=>{...})`

because of compileComponentAsync is a promise you must use `then(...)` to get factory

http://plnkr.co/edit/WUHafVZiSBcbjazGflpj?p=preview

Comment: ok but still how do I load a URL, as this is what I am after... tx

Comment: my goal is to load this component dynamically: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplate/master/src/comps/app2/notes/LoadMeComp.ts'

Comment: this is how far I got: http://plnkr.co/edit/TzlP5HIqkW6kmUoLoQZG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

found solution:

```
import { Compiler,Component, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {HelloComponent} from './hello.component'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Dynamicaly Add Elements</h2>
      <button (click)="addItem()">add hello</button>
      <div #placeholder></div>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppComponent { 

  @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef;
  private componentFactory: any;

  constructor(public compiler:Compiler) {  
    const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplate/master/src/comps/app2/notes/LoadMeComp.ts';
    const importer = url => Observable.fromPromise(System.import(url));

    importer(url).subscribe((component) => {
      this.componentFactory = this.compiler.compileComponentSync(component['LoadMeComp']);
    });
  }

  addItem () {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0);
  }
}
```